# EF Dynamic contains does not work as expected

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm using the EntityFramework and the library 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core' for dynamically selecting records based upon an array of values.

It works fine for `int[]` but it returns funky SQL with `string[]`.

```
var whereQuery = _context.Registrations.AsQueryable();

int[] intArray = new[] {1, 2, 3};
string[] array = new[] {"A001", "D444"};

whereQuery = whereQuery.Where($"@0.Contains(RegistrationId)", intArray);
whereQuery = whereQuery.Where($"@0.Contains(Code)", array);
```

When debugging I see it generated the following SQL statment

```
...
FROM [dbo].[Registrations] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[RegistrationId] IN (1, 2, 3)) 
AND (( CAST(CHARINDEX([Extent1].[Code], N'A001') AS int)) > 0)
```

For the `int[]` it generates the correct / expected "IN-statement".

For the `string[]` it only checks for the first value from the array. I would expect:

```
AND ([Extent1].[Code] IN (N'A001', N'D444'))
```

**Versions :**

System.Linq.Dynamic.Core v1.0.14.0  (runtime v4.0.30319)

EntiftyFramework  v6.0.0.0

What I am I missing?

Comment: What dynamic library are you using / what version exactly?

Comment: added the versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `List<string>` instead of an `string[]` solves the problem.

For more information also see :

https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/issues/61

> This is not a bug.
>
> The reason is that you test fails because you provide an array in the
>   Where clause as the params.. This actually means that if you provide
>   an array like { "A001", "D444" }, the code tries to replace @0 by "A001",
>   and tries to replace @1 by "D444" and so on. But you only have defined
>   @0.

Reply to "Not a bug" above. 
Yes, my sample displays two times @0. This is just sample code that I copied. The error remains even when using only 1 parameter.